# Accessing machine through wifi

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wifi, remote-access, file-sharing

I have one computer running ubuntu operating system. It is having a wifi router connected to it. I have other laptop which runs windows 7 operating system.

Is there a way to access the ubuntu machine from windows machine through wifi and vice versa ?

Comment: 1. Try an FTP server like FileZilla. 2. Off topic; belongs on Super User.

Comment: FileZilla is having both client and server available. What should i install in ubuntu ? What in windows ?

Comment: Hey, did you read the word "server" I put after the word "FTP?" That means use the server ;) Install that on Ubuntu, and you'll have an FTP server running. Then access it through your web browser on Windows, using an `ftp://someip/somepath` URL. Alternatively, connect using an FTP client on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) in both windows and linux. It will give you full control of the remote machine but I'm not sure if you can do file transfering...

For file transferring, connecting from windows to linux I would use [*winSCP*](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php), which access files through ssh, so you would have to install an run sshd on your linux box. If you haven't sshd in your ubuntu box, install it by doing `$ sudo apt-get install ssh`. You can start ssh daemon in ubuntu 11.10 with the command `$ sudo service ssh start`. From linux (Ubuntu 11.10) to windows (w7), I have successfully got into w7 machines in my local network by exploring the Network section in the left bar of the nautilus explorer. Sometimes, for some folders it would ask me for credentials to log into the remote machine, and file transferring was as simple as doing copy and paste (Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v)

hope to be helpful! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

VNC is good for remote work on both Windows and Linux.  You'll need to install VNC on Windows but I believe it comes by default with Ubuntu.  You need to configure one to be the server and then you can use a client from the other machine to connect to it and remotely control the server machine.

Here are some resources for VNC in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC

And I use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) when I'm working on Windows (server and client included in the install).

Answer (score 0):

Install XRDP on Ubuntu.
on windows then run msrtc -v

if over the internet , I say use
https://www.dwservice.net/en/download.html
free and lot better than teamviwer.